# How do I remove the white blank in table?

Tags: r

When I read table in R, I get this table. You can see that, there is a huge gap between `Scored` and `Annotation` text.

How I remove the white blank between them?

Or how I cut the huge string? More be precise: How can I fix table size (and it will be cut automatically).

[image]

When i print the table in shiny UI it's seem like this:

[image]

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Is this for export to a file? Possibly a pdf? If not, why do you care about the layout?

Comment: I print the table in UI using shiny. and it's seems ugly.

Comment: Please show a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/1412059).

Comment: A screenshot is not useful at all. Follow the link I provided.

Comment: If `df` is your dataframe, `print(df, right=FALSE)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your annotation text is right aligned. Make it left aligned or have your
Annotation comes in the first column and the for a better look.